# Flutter pushNotification ios Missing Push Notification Entitlement warning - can't receive pusher notifications when the app in testflight

Tags: xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, testflight, provisioning-profile

it is my first time using notifications in my app when I try to upload my app on a test flight I got a Missing Push Notification Entitlement warning message from apple and the notifications won't work I tried so many things but I'm stuck at this point, I'm using pusher service for the notifications I tried everything but still can't receive notifications